# How to redirect shell output to variable with iteration in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to iterate over each elements in array called `envContentKeys = ["Address", "Name", "Date"]`to create new environment variables for each element in the array by redirect the value in json file `config.json`.

here's the `config.json`

```
{
   "dev":{
          "Name": "Apple",
          "Address": "somewhere",
          "Date": "10Sep2021"
         },

   "prod":{
          "Name": "Orange",
          "Address": "somewhere2",
          "Date": "15Sep2021"
         }
}
```

What I did in the pipeline is calling `.each` and assign element in `envContentKeys` as an env

```
 envContentKeys.each {
     env."${it}" = sh(
                      script: "jq -r '.${params.environment}.${it}' config.json",
                      returnStdout: true
                   ).trim()
 }
```

`${params.environment}` will be whether `dev` or `prod` depends on user's selection.

the final result should looks like this

for dev
`env.Address = somewhere`
`env.Name = Apple`
`env.Date = 10Sep2021`

however, the pipeline gives the error

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@63b12f64
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@6c55c234
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LoopBlockScopeEnv@498d2924
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@748e1123
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureCallEnv@16dc3a96
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@29d584b3
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@691424c3
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@1769e279
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@2ec694c5
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@767fe543
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2bd4e7db
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2bd4e7db
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr
```

Comment: It sounds like all you want is `Map config = readJSON(file: 'config.json')` for the JSON load and parse, and then `env << config[params.environment]` for the Map merge. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work without using shell.

```
params.environment = 'prod'
...

def cfg = readJSON file:"config.json"
env.putAll( cfg[ params.environment ] )
```

---

if you still want to use shell to evaluate json-path...

jenkins pipeline tries to serialize-and-store all variables between steps because each next step could be running on different node.

The error like `java.io.NotSerializableException` means you have such variable that is not serializable.

`java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr` should give you a hint that it happens somewhere around array. and `Itr` - that's about iterator (guess).

actually `array.each {}` is using iterator..

2 main options to fix it

**1. try to change non-serializable to serializable objects**

`java.util.ArrayList$Itr` is not serializable but ArrayList itself is serializable - look for `All Implemented Interfaces: Serializable` in corresponding [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

so, array itself is fine, you could try to change the way you are iterating the array to a standard `for`

```
for (int i=0; i<envContentKeys.size(); i++){
    def it = envContentKeys[i]
    env[it] = sh(...)
}
```

can't check this now but i think it should work because all variables used in loop are serializable.

**2. use @NonCPS annotation around code that causing the issue**

move your code into function and add `@NonCPS` annotation to this function. this will force pipeline to execute it as one non-breakable step.

```
@NonCPS
def myFunction() {
    envContentKeys.each {
        env[it] = sh(...)
    }
}
```